# Inserting Russian characters in table when file is loaded from SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to insert some value that is having Russian characters from SSIS.

Say I have a `MYDATA.TXT` (comma separated) and data as below

```
REM,DES,ID
FR1,Головка,8
GY2,6-гр,9
MO0,Болт,2
```

1st row is column headers. I'm using this in Flat file. After executing the task, the value are different in my table something like `Ð“Ð¾Ð»Ð¾Ð²ÐºÐ°`

After some research I found that i have to use `N` before the text and column should be `NVARCHAR`. But i'm not sure how to do this in SSIS. I have around 1.2 million records, should I prefix my column with `N` for all rows or is there any other way in `SSIS`?

Comment: The equivilent to `nvarchar` in SSIS datatype is the Unicode String or `DT_WSTR`. YOu'll also need to ensure you let SSIS know the code page that the file is stored in, to make sure it reads the characters correctly. Considering that that now look like `Ð“Ð¾Ð»Ð¾Ð²ÐºÐ°`, this suggests you are importing the values as a `DT_WSTR`, but using the wrong code page/encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the code page to 65001 (UTF-8).

[image]

In Advanced tab change the Datatype of DES column to unicode string [DT_WSTR]

[image]

Output:

[image]